# django How can I get a weekly average queryset

Tags: python, django

I have two models that are linked.  Here is a subset for simplicity:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    event = models.OneToOneField(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    completion_time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, null=True, blank=True)
    labor_price = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Final Labor Price', blank=True, null=True)
```

and:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, null=True, blank=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

I need to get a few things, and I know they can be done in SQL, but I'm not sure how to do them in django.  I need monthly and weekly averages for the `labor_price` of jobs.  In other words, something like this, and I may have it wrong for what I'm doing, as I haven't tested it:

```
SELECT `schedule_event.start_time`, AVG(`jobs_job.labor_price`)
FROM jobs_job
INNER JOIN schedule_event on jobs_job.event_id = schedule_event.id
GROUP BY YEAR(`schedule_event.start_time`), MONTH(`schedule_event.start_time`)
HAVING COUNT(`schedule_event.start_time`) = DAY(LAST_DAY(`schedule_event.start_time`));
```

I also need to get the average hourly labor price for the week, but I'm not quite sure how that would work at the moment.  It would be a query that would do something like  `average(labor_price/(completion_time - event__start_time))` on a given filter of dates.

Comment: I would do it as raw query. Even if it is possible to it with django ORM code will be less readable than your simple SQL. And ORM query can be not optimal.

Comment: I'll have to get that query working.  It's one I would have used with mysql, but it doesn't seem to work with pgsql, because of timezone aware timestamps, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this, or had time to work on the average hourly labor price for the week, but I believe the following should give you the weekly and monthly averages for labor price:

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.db.models import Avg

now = datetime.now()

weekly_avg = Job.objects.filter(event__end_time__lte=now, event__start_time__gt=now-datetime.timedelta(days=7)).values('labor_price').aggregate(Avg('labor_price'))
monthly_avg = Job.objects.filter(event__end_time__lte=now, event__start_time__gt=now-datetime.timedelta(days=30)).values('labor_price').aggregate(Avg('labor_price'))
```

Comment: I had gotten something very similar.
`context['previous_week_average'] = Job.objects.filter(event__start_time__gt=timezone.now() - timedelta(days=7), event__start_time__lt=timezone.now(), labor_price__isnull=False).aggregate(average_price=Avg('labor_price'))['average_price']`